# CSS center div with <p> to parent div, vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS where I try to center a `div` with some `<p>` to their parent `div` wrapper. I tried to use the well known `translate(-50%, -50%)` solution, but it does not work. I also tried to use `margin: 0 auto`, also without success. I think I am missing a point, but I dont get it. Could someone tell me?

Hint: This is an MCVE constructed from only the relevant HTML and CSS rules, there are a lot of more so dont be confused about some `display:block` or an `!important`. I coloured the background and borders for better visualization.

Here is the snippet:

```css
.half-width {
  width:50%;
  height: 795px;
}

div, p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {

  font-family: 'IBMPlexSans';
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container{
    display:flex;  
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .mobile-only{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
  }
  /** for switching between mobile and desktop rules **/
  .desktop-only{
   display: none;
  }
  
  .background-black{
 background-color: #4E4E4E !important;
 width: 650px !important;
 border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .size-35{
   font-size: 35px;
   height: 526px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .size-25{
   font-size: 25px;
   width: 335px;
   height: 95px;
  }
  
    .size-19{
   font-size: 19px;
   width: 335px;
   height: 350px;
   margin-top: -25px;
  }


/** center container div to an unknown body, works fine **/
  .center-to-bg{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  .height-495{
   height: 495px;
  }
  
  .height-526{
   height: 526px;
  }
  .desc-text > p{
   display: block;
  }
  
/** center the content div with the text to its parent,
horizontally AND vertically, does not work**/
  .center-text{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .center-text > p{
   display: block;
  }
  
  .center-h{
   display: block !important;
   left: 50%;
  }
 
 
 .half-width{
   width: 100vw;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<div class="half-width mobile-only background-black height-526 center-to-bg">
  <div class="center-text color-white size-35" id="section2">
 <p>ThIS IS </p>
 <p>Á PARAGRAPH</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="half-width mobile-only center-to-bg">
  <div class="center-text color-white size-19">
        <div class="desc-text">
        <p>This is a long text that needs to be centered over multiple lines</p>
          <p>
          Because mobile devices are not that width
          </p>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is one of the most asked questions on SO (in CSS), please search better before ask ;)

Comment: dippas as I stated I already tried the answers suggested there

Answer (score 0):

when you will center an element in a parent you can give the parent:

display: table;
height: 100vh;

and the child:

vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;

```css
.outer {
    display: table;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: yellow;
}

.inner {
vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner div text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and without table?:)